# Deleting phpMyAdmin setup.php

Tags: php, web-server, log-files, website

My website log files show many requests looking for:

```
/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php
```

I have phpmyadmin on my website. Am I supposed to delete that `setup.php` file or just let them keep on requesting it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Yes, Delete it. Also delete the entire `setup` directory.

**Long Answer:** In the past, there have been numerous code-injection vulnerabilities related to phpmyadmin's `setup.php`. Since the file is only used for initial setup purposes, and is not intended to be used post-installation, there is nothing to be lost, and potentially much to gain, by deleting it.

Furthermore, the installation instructions for phpmyadmin recommend deleting the entire `setup` directory after installation. One of the suggestions found at http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#securing-your-phpmyadmin-installation reads as follows:

> Remove the setup directory from phpMyAdmin, you will probably not use it after the initial setup.

So, yes, delete `setup.php` *and* delete the entire `setup` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Steps for [Securing your phpMyAdmin installation](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#securing-your-phpmyadmin-installation) are introduced in phpMyAdmin’s documentation. That includes **removing the whole setup directory** after the installation.

You could also improve the security by

- disabling login with user accounts that have access to multiple databases, e.g. root
- using non-default paths, something else than /phpmyadmin
- not publishing /phpmyadmin on every domain but a single vhost like https://tools.example.com/

In general in this kind of situations, you can always create directory based restrictions to your Apache vhost. This way you don't need to remove files of which you don't know for sure whether they can be removed. This will also prevent these files coming back on updates. If you need more general protection against automated vulnerability scans, you could use [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).